# Use sed with jq in bash script

Tags: bash, jq

How to use sed with jq to replace _ in key name with symbol a

> { "product_name":"kl" }

should become

> { "productaname":"kl" }

in a bash script

Answer (score 3):

No need for `sed`; it's easy to do in just `jq`:

```
$ jq '{ productaname: .product_name }' <<<'{ "product_name":"kl" }'
{"productaname":"kl"}
```

If you want to replace underscores with a's in all keys of an object:

```
$ jq 'with_entries(.key |= gsub("_"; "a"))' <<<'{ "product_name":"kl", "foo_bar":12 }'
{"productaname":"kl","fooabar":12}
```

From the documentation for `with_entries`:

> `to_entries, from_entries, with_entries`
>
> These functions convert between an object and an array of key-value pairs. If `to_entries` is passed an object, then for each k: v entry in the input, the output array includes `{"key": k, "value": v}`.
>
> `from_entries` does the opposite conversion, and `with_entries(foo)` is a shorthand for `to_entries | map(foo) | from_entries`, useful for doing some operation to all keys and values of an object. `from_entries` accepts key, Key, name, Name, value and Value as keys.

Comment: @priyanshukumar Stuff like that needs to go in your question.

Comment: it was just for an example

Comment: do you have a answer to this ?

Comment: @priyanshukumar If neither of those do what you need, you *really* need to go back to your question and make it clearer.

Comment: any example of this how to do the specified case with with_entries @shawn